# Как правильно подключить меню на JavaScript, чтобы оно было на 5 разных страницах?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jsp

Есть, например, 5 *jsp-* (или  *html-*) страниц. Например, с такими именами:

```
index.jsp
page1.jsp
page2.jsp
page3.jsp
page4.jsp
```

Я открываю первой `index.jsp` и вижу там какую то информацию, и меню, из 5 элементов, нажатие на которые открывает эти страницы. Меню — это  *javaScript*  и *CSS*.

Когда я нажимаю на любой элемент меню, открывается соответствующая страница. и на каждой странице, тоже какая-то информация, и точно такое же меню, выделенное на том элементе которому соответствует открытая страница.

Вот так выглядит это на `index.jsp`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <%--<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/menu.css" />" rel="stylesheet">--%>
    <%--<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/my.js" />"></script>--%>
    <script src="../resources/js/my.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/menu.css" />

...

<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="job_seeker">Job Seeker</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Для того, чтобы это меню отображалось на каждой странице, мне обязательно писать один и тот же код, с подключением  *javaScript*, *css* или можно как-то избавиться от копипаста?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно страницы собираются из других страниц, если у Вас есть повторяющийся контент. Cоздается макет, в случае spring посмотрите на использование директивы `<%@ include file="относительный url" %>`. Хотя думаю там есть и более продвинутые способы собирания страниц.

Фактически, код сведется к следующему:

```
<html>
...
<%@ include file="head.jsp" %>
...
<%@ include file="navigation.jsp" %>
...
</html>
```

В файлах соответсвенно уже описываются ваши повторяющиеся строки.

Comment: правильнее расширение должно быть jspf. соответственно и содержимое должно несколько отличаться от jsp.